# Check whether this matrix is symmetric in relation to the main diagonal

Tags: java, matrix

Given the number n, not exceeding 10, and a matrix of size n × n. 
Check whether this matrix is symmetric in relation to the main diagonal. Output the word “YES”, if it is symmetric and the word “NO” otherwise.

This is my code, it unfortunately does not work. Please, explain to me how to do it correctly :)

```
public class Main { public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n= scanner.nextInt();
    int[][] number = new int[n][n];
    boolean ismatch = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        number[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
      }
    }
    int unevenchecker = (n% 2);
    if (unevenchecker != 0) {
      for (int k = 0; k < number.length - 1; k++) {

        for (int l = 0; l < number.length - 1; l++) {
          if (number[k][l] == number[l][k]) {
            ismatch = true;
          }
        }
      }
      if (ismatch) {
        System.out.print("YES");
      }
    } else {
      System.out.print("NO");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is dim defined? What is its value if it's defined outside?

Comment: All you need is to find a single mismatch. Then you can exit your loops.

Comment: First of all, it is not clear, what do you mean by `Check whether this matrix is symmetric in relation to the main diagonal`? After that, what `dim` value is? Please, provide some test cases

Comment: the logic seems incorrect: you start with `ismatch = false` and when you find one match it is changed to `true` no matter how many mismatches there are. Start with `true` and when/if you find a mismatch, turn it to `false` (and end the loop). Also the ìf-else`s are not matching correctly....

Comment: What is the evenness check for? A matrix with odd dims can certainly be symmetric, consider `[[1]]`

Comment: @harold sure, but he is outputting `NO` if it is even (`if (n % 2 != 0) ... else ... NO...`), despite these can also be symmetric... `[[1 1][1 1]]`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger whatever, even then: `[[1, 0], [0, 1]]`

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n= scanner.nextInt();

    int[][] number = new int[n][n];
    boolean flag=true;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        number[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = i; j < n - i; j++) {
        if (number[i][j] != number[j][i]) {
          flag = false;
          break;

        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(n==0?"NO":flag==false?"NO":"YES");
  }

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n= scanner.nextInt();

    int[][] number = new int[n][n];
    boolean flag=true;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        number[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = i; j < n - i; j++) {
        if (number[i][j] != number[j][i]) {
          flag = false;
          break;

        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(n==0?"NO":flag==false?"NO":"YES");
  }

Comment: @PawełWalczuk code is not really readable if you post it in a comment like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix is **not** symmetric if you find at least 1 symmetric couple where the 2 parts are not equal, so instead of checking for equality inside the loop, check for **inequality**:

```
  ismatch = true;
  for (int k = 0; k < number.length - 1; k++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < number.length - 1; l++) {
      if (number[k][l] != number[l][k]) {
        ismatch = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    static boolean isSymmetric(int mat[][], int size) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size - i; j++) 
                if (mat[i][j] != mat[j][i]) 
                    return false;
        return true; 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n= scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] number = new int[n][n];
        boolean ismatch = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
              number[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }

        if (isSymmetric(number, n)) {
            System.out.print("YES");
        } else {
            System.out.print("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the nested loop into `isSymmetric` starts from `j = i + 1`, for not checking twice same condition.